# JScrollPane not working on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I am trying to implement the JScrollPane plugin on my website. Having taken a look through numerous FAQ/tutorials for this and double checked my scripts but cannot see where something is going wrong.

All of the scripts are being correctly referenced, I am calling the latest version of the JQuery library and I have the CSS being called before the scripts.

The page I am trying to implement this on is:

http://theindiecinema.com/walking-backwards/99 (click on the rate button on the right side of the tv)

To see the scrolling box that the JScrollPane should be being applied I have set up a duplicate page but with the JScrollPane stuff removed:

http://theindiecinema.com/testing-nopane

Please can I get some advice of how I can get this working.

Much Appreciated

Francis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call jScrollPane on .commentslist when it's revealed (by clicking Rate), not on $(document)ready. jScrollPane is having trouble initializing while the target element's parent is hidden. You should only have to do this once, but it won't really even matter if you re-call it every time you show #comments.

Alternately, you could un-hide #comments in your external CSS, then on document-ready, first initialize jScrollPane on .commentslist and then hide #comments.

Comment: Perfect, thanks - I changed it so that #comments was not hidden via CSS and instead used document ready JQuery to hide it.

This allowed the JScrollPane to work on the .commentslist so it is now all working ok

Many thanks again

Comment: Very glad to be of assistance!